# Fix Error Codeigniter : Call to a member function pilihkat() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Error :

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_result::$Input_model

Filename: controllers/Input_App.php

Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_app\application\controllers\Input_App.php
Line: 18
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_app\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

**and**

Fatal error: Call to a member function pilihkat() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_app\application\controllers\Input_App.php on line 18

My controller

```
    class Input_App extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');                    
    $this->load->model('Input_model','input_app'); 
}

public function index()
{
    $this->db->from('referensi_kategori');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $load['pilihkategori'] = $query->Input_model->pilihkat()->result();

    $this->load->view('input_view',$load);
}
```

Model (pilihkat())

```
        public function pilihkat(){
    $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->join('referensi_kategori','referensi_kategori.id_kategori = data_aplikasi.id_kategori','left');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

View (Select dropdown from data_kategori)

```
    <tr>
                                        <td>Kategori</td>
                                        <td><select name="data_kategori" class="form-control"required id="data_kategori" style="width:85%;">
                                        <option value='0'>-- pilih kategori --</option>
                                            <?php foreach ($pilihkategori as $kat) {
                                                echo "<option value=".$kat->id_kategori.">".$kat->data_kategori."</option>";
                                            }?>
                                        </select></td>
                                    </tr>
```

How to fix this error ?

Comment: model not loaded properly

Comment: but, how to fix this error ?

Comment: try my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the `model` like this

```
$this->load->model('Input_model','input_model');  //here input_model is alias name
$this->load->model('Input_app','input_app');  //here input_app is alias name
```

(or)

```
$this->load->model(array('Input_model','input_app')); // pass as array mutiple modal .in below i'm using this one
```

remove result() in controller while calling model because in model your returning result() so in controller no need to call it again.

```
 $load['pilihkategori'] = Input_model->pilihkat();
```

**Controller :**

```
    public function index()
    {

        $load['pilihkategori'] = Input_model->pilihkat();

        $this->load->view('input_view',$load);
    }
```

**Model :**

```
  public function pilihkat()
      {
            $this->db->select('*');    
            $this->db->from('referensi_kategori');
            $this->db->join('referensi_kategori','referensi_kategori.id_kategori = data_aplikasi.id_kategori','left');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query->result();
        }
```

Comment: that give error  Message: Class Input_app already exists and doesn't extend CI_Model, sorry newbie ..

Comment: . you have to load the module once only  so .use this one line only in constructor $this->load->model(array('Input_model','input_app'));  not starting two lines

Answer (score 0):

In your controller need to change two things.

1.Load more than one models like this.

```
$this->load->model(array('Input_model','input_app'));
```

2.Remove `result()` Because you already done it in model.

```
public function index()
{

    $load['pilihkategori'] = $query->Input_model->pilihkat();

    $this->load->view('input_view',$load);
}
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Filename: controllers/Input_App.php

Line Number: 22

Comment: see in your model `Input_app`.

Comment: try edited answer.why this two lines  `$this->db->from('referensi_kategori');
    $query = $this->db->get();` in controller.